# memcpy(), segmentation fault when changing the value of a predefined variable

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, memcpy

I wrote a program for handling command line inputs. I am having a segmentation error during memcpy() function when long strings are used as the input.

Here is the code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    // initialize input variables
    char inputFileName[] = "sequence.txt"; //default input file name
    //check if a different file name is given
    for(int i = 0; i < argc-1; i++){ 
        if(string(argv[i])=="-i"){ 
            cerr << "string: " << string(argv[i+1]).c_str() << endl;
            cerr << "string size: " << string(argv[i+1]).size() << endl;
            inputFileName[string(argv[i+1]).size()]=0;
            cerr << "filename: " << inputFileName << endl;
            memcpy(inputFileName,string(argv[i+1]).c_str(),string(argv[i+1]).size());
            cerr << "filename after memcpy: " << inputFileName << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When a short file name is given (-i sequence.fasta) it works properly:

```
$ ./Program -i sequence.fasta

string: sequence.fasta
string size: 14
filename: sequence.txt
filename after memcpy: sequence.fasta
filename final: sequence.fasta
```

However a long name causes a segmentation fault:

```
$ ./Program -i sequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequence.fasta

string: sequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequencesequence.fasta
string size: 86
filename: sequence.txt
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Am I missing something? How should I handle memcpy()?

Comment: `inputFileName` won't be large enough to store the results, so you will be writing to memory that has not been allocated, which is undefined behavior, crashing is one possible result.

Comment: The easiest way would be to not use `memcpy`.

Comment: Just use `std::string` for `inputFileName`, and dispense with the `memcpy` for `operator=`.

Answer (score 1):

This is your problem:

```
  inputFileName[string(argv[i+1]).size()]=0;
```

inputFileName has predefined size equals to strlen("sequence.txt") + 1 == 12bytes + 1byte for '\0'

```
  char inputFileName[] = "sequence.txt"; //default input file name
```

so if you index it using string(argv[i+1]).size() then behaviour is undefined, if argv[i+1] is longer than 13.

You should use std::string, as a buffer

Comment: I would suggest just using `std::string` for `inputFileName`.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from that the size of array

```
char inputFileName[] = "sequence.txt";
```

is fixed and equal to 13 your code has another bug. When you execute memcpy

```
memcpy(inputFileName,string(argv[i+1]).c_str(),string(argv[i+1]).size());
```

then you do not copy the terminating zero because expression `string(argv[i+1]).size()`does not take it into account.